# Do local applications or ingestion of Gaultheria help treating a tendinitis?

Tags: tendinitis, natural-remedy, epicondylitis

I have read some claims that local applications or ingestions of Gaultheria help treating a tendinitis.

[Mercola](http://articles.mercola.com/herbal-oils/wintergreen-oil.aspx):

> Pain relief - The most popular health benefit of wintergreen oil is its pain-relieving effects, which can help alleviate headache, muscle cramps, joint pain, tendonitis, and bone pain. Wintergreen oil also helps drive out stress and tension.

[sports-sante](http://www.sports-sante.com/index.php/anti-inflammatoire-naturel-l-huile-essentielle-de-gaultherie-odorante):

> [L'huile essentielle de Gaulthérie odorante (Gaulthéria fragrantissima)] sera utilisée en massage pour toutes les douleurs musculaires ou articulaires (tendinites, entorse, claquage musculaire, lumbago, arthrose). Elle est très appréciée des sportifs.

[Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00QHD4LC2):

> The main chemical component in Wintergreen, methyl salicylate, is used in topical joint creams to soothe sore muscles and joints.

Is there any scientific evidence supporting or infirming the usefulness of local applications or ingestions of Gaultheria to treat a tendinitis? I am mostly interested in the lateral epicondylitis of the humerus.

If so, what is the recommended use? (number of applications per day, quantity to use, before/after physical effort, morning/evening, etc.)