# Improving the penetrability of essential oils used to treat a tendinitis

Tags: natural-remedy, tendons, essential-oil

Some essential oils, such as Gaultheria procumbens, contain [methyl salicylate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methyl_salicylate), which is a cyclooxygenase inhibitor. As a result, some believe it may be of some use to treat tendinities (e.g., (1), although it is quite debated (2,3)).

The simplified mechanism is as follows (source: (4)):

[image]

Is there any way to improve the penetrability of oil used to treat a tendinitis (e.g., diluting the oil with some cream)?

I am mostly interested in the lateral epicondylitis of the humerus.

---

(1) Corrand, Laura. La place des huiles essentielles dans la prise en charge des douleurs articulaires et musculaires à l'officine. Diss. 2013.

(2) Matthews, P., et al. "Topical rubefacients for acute and chronic musculoskeletal pain in adults." (2011).

(3) [Do local applications or ingestion of Gaultheria help treating a tendinitis?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/4159/43)

(4) http://www.medicine.ox.ac.uk/bandolier/booth/painpag/topical/topintro.html